# Create concatenate function in Haskell: [String] -> String

Tags: string, list, haskell, fold

I'm having a lot of trouble getting this function to work:

```
concatenate :: [String] -> String
```

It is designed to simply take a list of strings and return a single string that is the result of the concatenations of each element of the list from head to tail. I'm trying to stay within the `map`, `foldl`, and `foldr` functions. I feel like I know what the concept of these functions do well enough, but the most common problem I'm running into is that I'm having a conflict of types. GHC will expect a [Char] for example, and I'll put in code that is apparently trying to use a [[Char]] without me knowing it.

For example: `concatenate (x:xs) = foldr (++) x (concatenate xs)`

And I get the following compile error:

```
Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
Expected type: [[Char]]
  Actual type: String
In the return type of a call of `concatenate'
In the third argument of `foldr', namely `(concatenate xs)'
In the expression: foldr (++) x (concatenate xs)
```

I'm *very* new to Haskell, so please feel free to laugh. Harshness is expected, and welcomed, as long as an explanation fit for a newbie is also included. Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 12):

You actually don't need the recursive call there. The function `foldr` already simulates a recursive call. All you need to do is use:

```
concatenate :: [String] -> String
concatenate ls = foldr (++) "" ls
```

And remember that there's a [`concat` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat) already, which is more generic, as it works on any list of list (as opposed to simply list of strings).

Comment: And it was that simple... Thank you. It's pretty difficult for me to get into the mindset required for developing functions in Haskell after coming right from C. And about `concat`, I know it exists, but I'm trying to understand these basic functions by making my own versions. It's seemed to help in other languages in the past.